# Check between 2 elements of an array

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, genetic-algorithm

I have a random array of 20 elements given by

```
int a[20] = {30,20,100,30,10,120,80,200,50,160,190,60,150,140,110,170,70,40,90,180};
```

I want to pickup 2 random elements from the array and check if there are any other values in the array which fall between these two values.
That is if the 2 values picked up are 130 and 140, then the function should return `true`.
On the other hand,if the 2 values picked up randomly are 130 and 150 then the function should return `false` as 140 lies between the 2 chosen values.

Is there an easier method to check this in C++.

Thanks.

Comment: DId you try anything at all?

Comment: I tried by using a if condition like if(a[i]==a[k]-10) and then running the variables i and k over the entire length of the array using a nested for loop.But the problem with this approach is that it is valid only with this specific type of array in which the difference between the numbers is 10.I was trying for something which works for a general array consiting of random numbers.

Comment: sort the array, then the condition for indices `i` and `j` is simply `max(i,j) - min(i,j) > 1`

Comment: @user 463035818 .I am not allowed to move the elements of the array as each number on every position corresponds to a starting time of an operation.

Comment: then make a copy and sort the copy, actually I dont understand why are are not allowed to sort the array but then you pick elements at random, they wont be less random when you pick them from a sorted array ;)

Comment: actually you dont need to sort the array at all, just pick two indices `i` and `j` at random from `[0,size)` and use my condition from above (which tells you if there would be elements in between if you would sort the array)

Comment: @avi *using a nested for loop* -- Once you went down that path, consider the solution unoptimal, and better solutions exist.   What if the array consisted of 10,000 elements instead of 20?  Using nested for-loops almost always gives the most naive "solution" that is available.

Answer (score 1):

That does exactly for what you asked, still very suboptimal, but it works :) With any type of array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>


using namespace std;

bool inRange(int low, int high, int x);
int main()
    {
    const int arrayLength = 20;
    int a[arrayLength] = {130, 20, 100, 30, 10, 120, 80, 200, 50, 160, 190, 
      60, 150, 140, 110, 170, 70, 40, 90, 180};

    int random = 0;
    int random2 = 0;
    srand(time(NULL));
    random = rand() % arrayLength + 1;
    random2 = rand() % arrayLength + 5;


    for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; ++i) {
        if (inRange(random, random2, a[i]) || inRange(random2, random,a[i])) 
        {
        return true;
      }
  }
getchar();
}

bool inRange(int low, int high, int x)
{
return (low <= x && x <= high);
}
```